# Offline first Spatial mobile database for cross platform development IOS, Android and Windows10?

Tags: android, ios, uwp, offlineapps, nosql

I am in the early stages of developing a mobile application that will rely heavily on spatial queries to find local business. I would really like to build it in an offline first and all queries ideally executed locally and transparently sync business in your current area in the background.

I would also like the search results contain the distance from specified location/current location. all offline!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to try this library for Android for simple spatial queries. You could take a look at this [splite-android](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android).

It is from a library called [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/home). I think it is written in C/C++.

A quick google search brought me to an article describing how to use it on iOS [here](https://aaronparecki.com/2015/05/21/11/).

I didn't find anything about Windows 10 but maybe you can import it yourself.

Comment: I require something that can be used on all three platforms!